# Сериализация JSON с последующей передачей в другой контроллер

Tags: objective-c, json

Застрял на таком моменте:
1 Класс:
Парсинг web-страницы, получение JSON, сохранение в NSArray.

2 Класс:
Наследует данные от 1 Класса, отвечает за отображение UIPickerView.

Суть проблемы: никак не могу отобразить NSArray из 1 Класса в UIPickerView
2 Класса.

Пробовал в 2 классе создать массив и действовать через него.
Не получается.
Что можно сделать?
Язык: Objective - C.
Спасибо.

```
    #import "GetAllStates.h"
    #import "TakeСontact.h"
    #define getStatesUrl                @"http://staging.api.kiteflightapp.com/v1/facilities/get_states"

  @interface GetAllStates ()

  @end

  @implementation GetAllStates
  @synthesize response,serverResponse;
  @synthesize GetstateArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

-(void)getStates:(NSString *)states api_key:(NSString *)key completion:   (void (^)(NSString *))completion
{


NSString *stringUrl = @"http://staging.api.kiteflightapp.com/v1/facilities/get_states?api_key=g4sksgk0kspscc4oogo8wow0w0ocossg000og0so";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                     if (!error && data){ // here you can check also response.statusCode if needed




                                 GetstateArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];



                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             completion(serverResponse);


                                             NSLog(@"%@",GetstateArray);


                                         });
                                     }else {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             completion(nil);
                                             //show some alert about no connection etc
                                         });
                                     }
                                 }] resume];

        }
  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
 #pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toStatesPicker"]) {
    TakeContact *addNewContact;
    addNewContact = [segue destinationViewController];
    addNewContact.showMyState = GetstateArray;   
}
```

}

// Класс 2,принимающий данные.

```
 #import "TakeСontact.h"
 #import "GetAllStates.h"
 @interface TakeContact ()    <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>



 @end

 @implementation TakeContact
 @synthesize showMyState;
 @synthesize stateMyArray;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

showMyState.delegate =self;//мой pickerView
showMyState.dataSource= self;



}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



 -(IBAction)SHOWMEJSON:(id)sender {

 }

 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


 }
 -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView   numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

return stateMyArray.count;
 }

 -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

return 1;;

 }
 -(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:  (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

return self.stateMyArray[row];
 }


@end
```

Comment: код можно посмотреть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, http://pastebin.com/xSkWJ290
Спасибо.

Comment: почему бы к вопросу не добавить?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да, стормозил. Сорри.
Не могу понять где именно допускаю ошибку. segue identifier настроен верно - проверил себя на всякий случай.
JSON в лог прилетает - там всё отображено.
Почему pickerView не видит данные - нет понимания..

Comment: и ваш класс объявлен делегатом и пикер точно к нему обращается за данными?

Comment: Я эти данные передаю через prepareForSegue. Класс 2 подписан на delegate и datasource.

Comment: либо выкладывайте все приложение, либо ставьте брейкпоинты и говорите где именно все теряется

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, если я выложу его архивом в чате - вам будет удобно посмотреть?

Comment: да где угодно. а что с вопросом то произошло?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, может лучше по почте?

Comment: вы ж вопрос задаете не мне лично, а всему комьюнити. как вы всем отправите по емейлу?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Прошу прощения. У меня мало опыта пользования ресурсом.
Подкорректировал вопрос.